# Android Navigation - How is it done?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, navigation, back-button

OK sorry this is a bit of a "stupid" question.

Currently I am developing an application with a number of views and XML files. If I click certain buttons the view changes etc.

BUT, I want it like stack. So if you go to Page 2, pressing the back button goes back to Page 1. Currently the back button destroys the activity and the application closes.

The only thing I can think of is to have states, so if the back button is pressed, set the view to State X, but I am not sure if this is the "correct programming technique" for Android.

Another thought was to have multiple Activities, so when a button is pressed, a new Activity is created on top of the old one. But this seems inefficient and stupid.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want multiple [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).

Activities and [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) have a lot of built-in knowledge about the [back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and make it easy to do just what you're describing while providing the user with a coherent experience.

Perhaps you could describe a bit more why you think this would be efficient for your application? Are you creating hundreds of Activities programmatically?

*Edit* - if you're coming from another mobile platform, where application parts are more tightly bound together, you might try thinking of Android apps as being more like web pages. The most common way to share information is via the query string (Intent) and the back button works because your are arriving at a new page (Activity) for each navigation.

Comment: Thanks for this. That was my original thought but my housemate said I was being stupid xD

Comment: Yeah, from the perspective of other platforms it may seem strange, but Android apps are more like "loose bundles of Activities" than single monolithic applications.

Comment: Well I didn't think it was going to be inefficient for my application as it's likely I am only going to have 3 levels. edit (pressed enter doh). I am just making a cooking app where you can browse receipes, then go into the recipe. But I imagine for bigger apps, creating activity after activity after activity will just take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The Widget Sample code, 'Wiktionary' on the android sdk site has some sample code for this in the [LookupActivity.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/LookupActivity.html) file.